# Eclipse project directory hierarchy

Tags: android, package

I heard that when packages are mapped into directories, package name should match the directory name exactly .But when I have gone through the directory hierarchy in eclipse i found a package named com.example.Timetable(say) .but the folder name it belongs to has a different name called src.Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, all packages go into the src folder. The matching of the package names starts from the subfolders of the src folder, e.g.

src/com/example/Timetable -> package name com.example.Timetable

The src folder itself is not part of the package name.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you.